# Create MySQL Workbench query plan image from command line / terminal

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, query-planner

Is there a way to create MySQL Workbench query plan image from command line or terminal and save it as an image something like this?

[image]

I checked the MySQL Workbench documentation here, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-command-line-options.html. But don't see any such option. So, is there a hack or even a separate tool to create this image? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See SchemaCrawler http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/diagramming.html

Comment: SchemaCrawler is the wrong answer. It's a tool to document a db structure. The question however is about visual explain (optimizer planning), which is a special feature in MySQL Workbench (JSON explain data is visualized in a graph).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in MySQL Workbench. The tool is a GUI application and as such not well suited for command line work. Maybe you can find a tool that can take the JSON output of `EXPLAIN` and builds a graphic from that.